# Login Page Design and Authorization

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

In my website, the Web.config is as follows:

```
 <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
         <assemblies>
            <add ..../>
         </assemblies>
       </compilation>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"></forms>
     </authentication>
     <authorization>
      <allow users="admin" />
      <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

I've tried to design the login page but it seems like whatever I do it doesn't appear, and after looking for a solution I'e found this:

> "i guess i got it. since you are
>   denying other pages in web config
>   unless user authenticated. Allow image
>   folder also in web config file like
>   you are allowing login page,similarly
>   allow image folder,css,javascript
>   folder etc. Image should show up in
>   page. It should work."

The problem is I don't know how to allow these folders, can anyone help?

Comment: can you post the info from your web.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to [location Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx):

> The location element specifies the
>   resource that child configuration
>   settings apply to and is also used to
>   lock configuration settings,
>   preventing the settings from being
>   overridden by child configuration
>   files.
>
> The location element can enclose other
>   elements, either to apply
>   configuration settings to a specific
>   resource or to lock the settings.

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Images">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add exceptions to your web.config file:

```
<location path="foldername">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```